# I am trying to send a video in a post request to my server which contains Python code and accepts video as request.files['video]

Tags: java, android, post, request

```
public void sendVideo(Uri videouri){

    //creating client
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    File videofile = new File(videouri.getPath());
    String pathofvid= videouri.getPath();
    Toast.makeText(this, "path of video: "+ pathofvid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //building request body
    RequestBody requestbody=  RequestBody.create(MediaType.
                    parse("multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001"),
                    "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video\"; " +
                            "filename=\""+videofile+"\";"+"\r\nContent-Type: " +
                            "video/*\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--\r\n");


    //build the request
    Request request= new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://muskan1017.pythonanywhere.com/gate-video-upload")
            .post(requestbody)
            .addHeader("User-Agent", "Your Guard Application")
            .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001")
            .build();

    //Execute the request..
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
            runOnUiThread(()->Toast.makeText(Entry_GateActivity.this
            ,"Failed to upload video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
            //Handling the response
            String jsonresponse = response.body().string();
            Log.d(TAG,"Response= "+jsonresponse);
        }
    });

}
```

This is my Java code in Android Studio. Every time I am getting the same default response irrespective of the URI I give.
Here is the VS Code thunder client snippet for the request:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video\"; filename=\"Test3.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--\r\n");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://muskan1017.pythonanywhere.com/gate-video-upload")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("Accept", "*/*")
  .addHeader("User-Agent", "Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)")
  .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

And here is my request picture:
[image: Post Request image:]

I think the video is not going to the server.
Is there any other code to do this request from Android Studio (Java)? Can anyone help please?